# Closing scope in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

In an express app I am able to do this

```
function donothing() {
}
donothing()
```

but not this

```
(function donothing() {
})()
```

The second sample fails with

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Why is that?

Comment: Works fine for me. What version of Node.JS are you using?

Comment: Using 0.8.1 in express app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `;` your code work correctly.

instead

```
 (function donothing() {
})()
```

use

```
;(function donothing() {
    })()
```

Comment: Node.js *is not* sensitive about semicolons (btw semicolon at the begining?). As long as you keep commands in separate lines it will be fine without semicolons. At least in Node 0.7+.

Comment: It seems that if there is something before the statement that could be interpreted as a function object you need to terminate the possibility. Just when I thought I was free of semi-colonic noise.